# How can I extract table data from an aspx file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I work in a call center and have an aspx page that generates a html table of the current stats of all the other call centers in the company.

I have put an example of what is generated on a [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/UqZjt/). I'm afraid I'm only an enthusiastic beginner so apologies if I'm not asking this correctly etc.

I am looking to extract just the data I need which includes all Rows and the Columns labeled:

```
         --- C6 C7 C13 C14
```

So all I need to see is the above columns.

This needs to be client side, so I assume JS, as we cannot access or edit on-server so we could not have our own aspx file for example.

I'm happy to use jQuery, I understand that one can extract data using jQuery but I can't seem to get my head around it :(

If anyone would be kind enough to put together a JSFiddle using http://fiddle.jshell.net/UqZjt/show/ as the source file, that would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It'd be nice if you could specify better what you mean by "extract". Do you want to to hide all other columns except those? Or display those columns' data separated based on which row the user selects? It's hard to answer if you don't specify your expected result. And more importantly, are you willing to use jQuery for this?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Thanks for the response. Yes, I would like to hide all the columns except the ones I listed. I am happy to use jQuery, I just don't have the experience to put it together myself - but I am sure I have seen examples of this before, I just didn't quite understand how to implement them.

Comment: You may as well update the question to include a detailed description - you know editing the question automatically bumps it to the top of the newest questions. I might be a little too sleepy to code a solution from scratch atm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're ok with jQuery, include the jQuery lib in your page adding this line to your page's `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here's the code to hide the unwanted columns based on a hard-coded array of headers:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //define which column headers to keep
    var headersToKeep = ['---', 'C6', 'C7', 'C13', 'C14'],
        colsToKeep = [],
        table = $('#gvRealtime'),
        ths = table.find('th');

    //iterates over headersToKeep retrieving their indexes
    $.each(headersToKeep, function(i, v) {
        //finds each header and adds its index to the colsToKeep
        colsToKeep.push(ths.filter(function() {
            return $(this).text() == v;
        }).index());
    });

    //makes a new jQuery object containing only the headers/cells not present in the colsToKeep
    $('th, td', '#gvRealtime, #gvTotal').filter(function() {
        return $.inArray($(this).index(), colsToKeep) == -1;
    }).hide(); //and hides them
});
```

Even though you don't have much experience with JS/jQuery, the code is commented in case you have any doubt of what each part does. Add it inside a `<script></script>` tag in the `<head>` after the jQuery lib.

Here's the [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/UqZjt/14/).

And of course, later on you can obtain/make the array based on checkboxes or other toggle method. As you didn't ask for any specific interface, I left the array hard-coded.

**edit:** And obviously, assuming you already know the column numbers instead of getting them through their headers' texts, you can use this much simpler snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var colsToKeep = [0, 6, 7, 13, 14];
    $('th, td', '#gvRealtime, #gvTotal').filter(function() {
        return $.inArray($(this).index(), colsToKeep) == -1;
    }).hide();
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/UqZjt/15/)**

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search brought me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4350046/785241), which brought me to [this fiddle](http://jsbin.com/oveva3/edit#javascript,html,live).

I have attempted to [adapt the code to your requirements](http://jsfiddle.net/Daedalus/UqZjt/7/).

Hopefully you can use that function(it's at the very bottom) to some effect.

Comment: @MaxArt The user mentions that they can't exactly understand jquery, which is why it isn't a requirement.  I do realize this, which is why I didn't do the very last function in jquery.  All I did is use the end-resulting data in a simple, and easy to understand js function.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily access the elements of a table in this way:

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0],
    tabArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < table.tBodies[0].rows.length; i++) {
    var rowArray = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < table.tBodies[0].rows[i].cells.length; j++)
        rowArray.push(table.tBodies[0].rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML);
    tabArray.push(rowArray);
}
```

Now, `tabArray` is a bidimensional array containing the content of the cell of the table.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think I understand how above code works... its looping through the data to build tabArray?? However, being a simple beginner - I don't quite know how I could use this to only display the Columns I listed in my Question. Would you be so kind as to mock up a JSFiddle using 'http://fiddle.jshell.net/UqZjt/show/' as the soucel

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('tr td').each(function() {
    $('#Result').append($(this).text());
});
});
```

​
In my example i have added a div with id result for the cell data

```
<div id="Result" ></div>
```