# how to map different classes within the same string using Google App Script and Cheerio?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, cheerio

Library used for *Cheerio* in *Google App Script*:

```
1ReeQ6WO8kKNxoaA_O0XEQ589cIrRvEBA9qcWpNqdOP17i47u6N9M5Xh0
```

---

---

---

I want to collect everyone's text `<td class="name large-link">` and of the `<td class="name large-link">` existing in a string, I tried to map it as follows:

```
function TestOne() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Test One');
  var url = sheet.getRange('Test One!A1').getValue();
  
  const contentText = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  const $ = Cheerio.load(contentText);

  //Menu do Plantel
  $('#page_team_1_block_team_squad_7-table > tbody > tr > td')
  .each((index, element) => {
  sheet.getRange(index+2,2).setValue($(element.shirtnumber).text());
  sheet.getRange(index+2,3).setValue($(element.name.large-link).text());
  });
}
```

Note: I want to fetch the texts of all the `class` that exist in the table, but since it's so big, I've summarized it in two `class` just so I can understand what I need to do and add the rest later.

But I wasn't successful in returning and I couldn't find examples of how I can make this collection, I would like an indication so that I don't need to do several different loopings and merge them all into one.

**The idea is to recreate this table in my spreadsheet:**

[image]

Here the sitemap:

https://int.soccerway.com/teams/norway/fotballklub-bodoglimt/1595/squad/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me, I got the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4350067/15391428) and made some modifications

```
   function myFunction() {
  const url = 'https://int.soccerway.com/teams/norway/fotballklub-bodoglimt/1595/squad/';
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Test One');
  const contentText = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  const $ = Cheerio.load(contentText);

  var header = Array();

  $("table tr th").each(function (i, v) {
    header[i] = $(this).text();
  })

  var data = Array();

  $("table tr").each(function (i, v) {
    data[i] = Array();
    $(this).children('td').each(function (ii, vv) {
      data[i][ii] = $(this).text();
    });
  })



  for (let i = 1; i < data.length - 6; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].length);
    console.log(data[i]);
    sh.getRange(i, 1, 1, data[i].length).setValues([data[i]]);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm away from home at the moment, as soon as I arrive I'll check it out and return with the possible answer verification that solves the question, thank you very much for taking the time to help me!

Answer (score 2):

The most practical option is not with script, you can use 'importHTML' function of Google Sheets

[image]

Documentation: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339?hl=en

Comment: Hello friend, I used this option and collected other data with ```IMPORTXML```, but unfortunately it joined many calls and reached the Google limit, causing the spreadsheet to get stuck waiting to load data.

So I need to use Google App Script to do the same service as before.